# Outlook Office 365 - how to get access token(through API) using username and App password when MFA is enabled?

Tags: oauth-2.0, outlook, microsoft-graph-api, office365, imap

As you all aware that MS Office 365 changed from Basic Auth to Modern Authentication recently, so it blocks all access from protocols such as IMAP/POP/SMTP. In that case we have to use Access token (OAUTH 2.0) generated from MS API by passing the client/secret, username , password & scope.

Currently, I'm able to get the access token for users who do not use MFA(able to access user mailboxes with IMAP protocol), but for the users who uses MFA, we have the app password for them. For mfa users, I'm passing their app password(in the password field) to get the access token, but I'm getting the following error

```
"error": "invalid_grant",
"error_description": "AADSTS50126: Error validating credentials due to invalid username or password.",
"error_codes": [
    50126
],
```

grant type I'm using for this request is "password". Any suggestion how to resolve this issue? Do I delegate any API permissions in azure ad application side? I have currently enabled IMAP accessforALL for my usage.

Please help.. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can't - the access and refresh tokens are retrieved through a browser-based login (which requires user interaction).

If you need to avoid that, you will need to register your app in Azure and application secret to authenticate without prompts.

Comment: As mentioned, I have already created an app in Azure and using the application secret, I'm able to get oAuth token for the users who don't have MFA(using normal password). But for the users who have been using MFA, we have the app password and sending it to get the token. At that time, I'm getting this error "invalid_grant" - AADSTS50126: Error validating credentials due to invalid username or password.

Comment: Does the following apply? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/399347/invalid-grant34-34error-description34-34aadsts5012.html

Answer (score 0):

While this is an old question, you can use the microsoft graph system.

Here is an example in php

```php
    $Secret = '**YourSecret**';
    $AppID = '**YourAppID**';
    $TenantID = '**YourTenantID**';
    $Username = '**YourUsername**';
    $Password = '**YourPassword**';


    $guzzle = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['headers' => ['User-Agent' => 'Token-Request']]);
    $url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/'.$TenantID.'/oauth2/v2.0/token';
    $token = json_decode($guzzle->post($url, [
        'form_params' => [
            'grant_type'    => 'password',
            'client_id'     => $AppID,
            'client_secret' => $Secret,
            'scope'         => 'https://outlook.office365.com/IMAP.AccessAsUser.All',
            'username'      => $Username,
            'password'      => $Password,
        ],
    ])->getBody()->getContents());

    $AccessToken = $token->access_token;
```